# Rasterize points QGIS average

Tags: qgis, point, vector, gdal-rasterize, average

When I convert points into raster using rasterize (vector to raster) tool, if there are two points in one pixel the pixel takes the bigger one. But I need the pixel to take the average of the values of the two points.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to first aggregate the points: to integrate several overlapping points to one single point and create the mean of the attribute value in question.

1. Create a new field `aggregate` with this expression to group together points in the same postion (or extremely close: here with a maximum distance of 0.1 meters) with this expression:

   ```
   array_max(array ($id, overlay_nearest( @layer, $id,limit:=-1, max_distance:=0.1)[0]))
   ```
2. Run `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Aggregate`, set the attribute created in step 1 as input for `Group by expression` and set the `Aggregate function` of the value you're interested in to `mean` (see screenshot).

   *By the way: it should be possible to skip step 1 and introduce the expression from there directly as `Aggregate function` in step 2. However, this did not work in my test setting.*
3. Rasterize the output of step 2.

*Red: initial points with their values, in the upper right part several overlapping points with values of 8 and 2; blue: aggregated points with the mean value of 5 for the points that were duplicates:*
[image]